# Looking for a sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am looking for a sorting algorithm to help me in my work. My objective is the following: after receiving an input of this kind:

```
5 4
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

The first line tells me how many ids I have, and the second number tells me how many connections. The following lines tell me the connections, and tell me that the first Id comes before the second one, for example: 1 comes before 2, 2 comes before 3, and so on. And if an impossible situation occurs:

```
3 2
1 2
2 3
3 1
```

or

```
2 2
1 2
2 1
```

I want to be able to send an error message.

Is there an algorithm that already does this? or can u give me some guide lines to how to start my work? I do not want ur code just some help/tips/advices. Thanks in advance for ur time.

Comment: This type of question is too broad for SO. If you had an algorithm in mind that you've already started implementing, you could ask a more specific question here. Asking for an algorithm recommendation can generate opinion-based answers or spam.

Comment: maybe [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) is better place to ask this ?

Comment: Quick answer though...any sorting algorithm will work. You just need to define the compare function for your data. In your case the compare function is defined by the input data.

Comment: Look for algorithms to detect cycles in directed graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I think you are probably looking for **topological sorting**.

It is based on the assumption that 'impossible situation' occurs when one connections suggests that A comes before B but there is some another connection which suggests that B comes before A.

Link for topological sort:
[Topological Sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)